# Map input array and get filtered array of object as result

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, object

I have below data coming from the backend.

```
priorities: [ 'get license', 'enroll college' ];
```

Now, I have a list of objects hardcoded at the front end.

```
studentPriorities = [
  { 
   prioritiesTitle: "get license",
   prioritiesDescription: "go to DMV and get your license"
  },
  {
   prioritiesTitle: "enroll college",
   prioritiesDescription: "gather fees and enroll for college"
  },
  {
   prioritiesTitle: "give exams",
   prioritiesDescription: "study hard for the exams"
  }
]
```

At any given time, I will get 2 priorities as a backend response. I need to search my hardcoded array of objects and get final data as follows.

```
mappedStudentPriorities = [
  { 
   prioritiesTitle: "get license",
   prioritiesDescription: "go to DMV and get your license"
  },
  {
   prioritiesTitle: "enroll college",
   prioritiesDescription: "gather fees and enroll for college"
  }
]
```

Can someone please suggest me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

This can be simply done using `Array.filter` & `Array.includes`.

Using `Array.includes`, you can check if the element is included in array or not and using `Array.filter`, you can get the filtered result which satisfies the condition.

```js
const priorities = [ 'get license', 'enroll college' ];

const studentPriorities = [
  { 
   prioritiesTitle: "get license",
   prioritiesDescription: "go to DMV and get your license"
  },
  {
   prioritiesTitle: "enroll college",
   prioritiesDescription: "gather fees and enroll for college"
  },
  {
   prioritiesTitle: "give exams",
   prioritiesDescription: "study hard for the exams"
  }
];

const result = studentPriorities.filter(({ prioritiesTitle }) => priorities.includes(prioritiesTitle));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use indexOf because includes is not supported by old and some new browsers

const result = studentPriorities.filter(({ prioritiesTitle }) => (priorities.indexOf(prioritiesTitle) !== -1));

console.log(result);

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Array.prototype.flatMap` on the array you get from the backend and then use `Array.prototype.filter` on the data entries.
A function could look like this:

```js
/** @param {string[]} priorities the titles you want to match */
function filterByPriorities (...priorities) {
  return priorities.flatMap(priority => studentPriorities.filter(({ prioritiesTitle }) => prioritiesTitle === priority))
}
```

The basic logic is:

- for each string in `input`

  - filter the `dataset` for all elements where:

    - `prioritiesTitle` matches `input`
- flatten the result of the previous operation
- `return` the result

Now there isn't much advantage here, but if the data gets more complicated, using a `for...of`-loop is often a good idea. The function below will give the same result, but for complex operations, this tends to be easier to understand and maintain.

- for each `entry` in `dataset`

  - if `input` includes entry title

    - push `entry` to `out-array`
- return `out-array`

```js
/** @param {string[]} priorities the titles you want to match */
function filter2 (...priorities) {
  const out = []
  for (const { prioritiesTitle, ...rest } of studentPriorities) {
    if (priorities.includes(prioritiesTitle)) out.push({ prioritiesTitle, ...rest })
  }
  return out
}
```

expected output for both is:

```js
[
  {
    prioritiesTitle: 'get license',
    prioritiesDescription: 'go to DMV and get your license'
  },
  {
    prioritiesTitle: 'enroll college',
    prioritiesDescription: 'gather fees and enroll for college'
  }
]
```

#### About `Array.prototype.includes`

A decent junk of developers recommends using `Array.prototype.indexOf` instead of `Array.prototype.includes` because `.includes` isn't available in every browser ever made.
But a few things are important to note on this:

- every common browser* (including their counterparts for mobile) has had `Array.prototype.includes` for close to 5 years
- depending on the engine, `.indexOf` for large data-sets can mean a massive speed penalty compared to `.includes` (from slightly slower if the item is at the end of the result, to a factor of 1000 times less `operations/s` in v8 (Chrome, nodejs etc) when the item is close to the start of the array. [*src*](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/es5-vs-es6-performance-comparisons-c3606a241633))
- **unless** you specifically have to support IE, there isn't much reason to not use `.includes` as the vast majority of users will use a browser that supports it.

**common browser -> browser with one of the usual JS-engines*

- v8 -> any Chromium based browser (Opera, Edge, Chrome)
- spidermonkey -> FireFox
- JavaScriptCore -> safari and allies